# Where can I find what filesystem lvm2 uses/

Tags: filesystem, ssd, lvm

After a default installation of Xubuntu (12.10) on a SSD card, I now have the following set up:

A SATA disk:
/dev/sda1 --> extended
  /dev/sda5 --> ext4 (mount point: /media/mark/

A SSD disk:
/dev/sdb1 --> ext2 (mount point: /boot)
/dev/sdb/2 --> extendend
  /dev/sdb5 --> lvm2 pv (mount point: xubuntu)

I am currently trying to find out what file system that lvm2 pv uses, since I hope it has journalling. I keep all my data and virtual machines on the SATA disk at the moment, just to make sure that I can re-install Xubuntu if necessary.

Can anyone tell me what file system lvm2 pv in Xubuntu is used/ Can anyone tell me if it's any good for SSD cards?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

LVM is a way to manage your data volumes in a flexible way : Your can picture it like a pool of virtual HD : Like any HD, it support every file system, and won't create it for you.

The basics steps are:

- Create some PV
- Create at least one volume group,
- create logical volumes in a group, allocate space for them from your physical volumes

These LVs appears as regular disks on your file system hierarchy (in `/dev/groupe-name/logical-vol-name`)

- **Finally** create a filesystem on your LV

Comment: Xubuntu did that default for me. My laptop runs Xubuntu fine, after some fiddling around to get a Logitech mouse and keyboard working...

So for some reason I only have an lvm, but no filesystem, yet my laptop runs fine. This is confusing to me. Can you help me out a little bit more, maybe by babysteps??

Comment: Can you provide the result of command `mount` ? You should perhaps include that in your question.

Comment: I finally found it. It has actually to do with the way you install Ubuntu, it seems.

I reinstalled Ubuntu, using default values. I made ext4 partitions before I started. Now I can see the filesystems in gparted. Both disks are now ext4.

Comment: LVM is usefull when managing many disks, but for a laptop, you'll be better without ;-)